# Pass A resultset outside the While Loop in Java

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Hello friends i have this class that is getting values from the database:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class EmailAlerts {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
SMTPAuthenticator sm = new SMTPAuthenticator();//new class
        Connection conn = null;
        String AtmName = "";
        String AtmBal = "";
        String atmsend = "";
        String[] bals = null;
 try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.80:1521:dev9i", "BI", "bi");
            Statement st1 = conn.createStatement();
            String atms = "select CLR_BAL_AMT, FORACID, ACCT_NAME from gam "
                    + "where BACID = 'ATM' and CLR_BAL_AMT < 100000";
            ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(atms);
            while (rs1.next()) {
                AtmName = rs1.getString("ACCT_NAME");
                AtmBal = rs1.getString("CLR_BAL_AMT");
                bals = AtmBal.split("\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < bals.length; j++) {
                    atmsend = AtmName + "-" + AtmBal;
                    //System.out.println(atmsend);
                }

            }
            System.out.println(atmsend);
}catch(Exception ad){
System.out.println(ad);
}

}
}
```

When I try to print out the variable "atmsend" outside the While loop, it only gives the last value in the database but inside the for loop, all the records from the database are there. How can I have all the records on the database outside the While loop?

Comment: your question is still not clear,,,, please elaborate.... there is some logical error... what is the actual output you require?

Comment: According to your logic it is obvious that the atmsend will contain the data like <value-ofAtmName>-<Value-of-Atmbal>.. you must be missing something

Comment: Yes atmsend will contain the ATMName and AtmBalance, so I need the different records in Different lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put in the variable `atmsend` all the values from the database, change this code:

`atmsend = AtmName + "-" + AtmBal;`

to this, although it is not recommended:

`atmsend += AtmName + "-" + AtmBal + "\n";`

You could use an `ArrayList<String>` and add all the values inside it while iterating them, instead of using a `String`

Comment: This Gives the results in one line. I need all the records in Different line each.

Comment: Now it puts them in different lines each

Answer (score 1):

```
atmsend = atmsend + AtmName + "-" + AtmBal +"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList <String> atmsend= new ArrayList<>();

Use Arraylist

 while (rs1.next()) {
                AtmName = rs1.getString("ACCT_NAME");
                AtmBal = rs1.getString("CLR_BAL_AMT");
                bals = AtmBal.split("\n");
                for (int j = 0; j < bals.length; j++) {
                    atmsend.add(AtmName + "-" + AtmBal+"\n");
                    //System.out.println(atmsend);
                }

System.out.println(atmsend.toString());
```

Comment: Can I have an Array with each value on its own line?

Comment: Can you check now ? or you can fetch each item from the arraylist and print them

Answer (score 0):

declare atmsend as String array

```
 String[] atmsend = null;
```

now when you store the value inside the while loop use

```
atmsend[i] = AtmName + "-" + AtmBal;
```

to retireve the string results

```
for(int i=0;i<atmsend.length();i++)
{
SYstem.out.println(atmsend[i]);
}
```

Comment: whoever downvoted , care to explain ?? i dont wanna repeat my mistake , so plz tell me